# How to search and sort a table in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have created a table and i wanted to sort and search the table using vue.js.
I referred this [link](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2021/03/11/adding-filtering-to-my-vuejs-table-sorting-and-pagination-demo) to do it
but still i couldn't do it.

Code is as below

```
  <div class="card">
    <div>
      <table style="margin-left:-25px;">
        <tr>
          <td><p style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:20px;color:black;font-weight:bold">Search</p></td>
          <td><input type="search" style="margin-top:0px;" v-model="filter" placeholder="Search"></td>
          <td><p style="margin-left:1080px;margin-top:20px;color:black;font-weight:bold">Add New Tool</p></td>
          <td><button class="btn"><input type="button" class="edit-btn" value="Add"></button></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tablediv table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
      <table class="Restable " id="ResouceTable" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:2px;" border="1">
        <thead class="Restable">
           <tr>
             <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' @click="sort('ProductID')">Product Id<font-awesome-icon id="homeIcon" :icon="['fas','sort']" size="lg" title="TaskStatus" style="font-size:18px;"/></th>
             <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' @click="sort('ProductTitle')">Product Title<font-awesome-icon id="homeIcon" :icon="['fas','sort']" size="lg" title="TaskStatus" style="font-size:18px;"/></th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' @click="sort('Description')">Description<font-awesome-icon id="homeIcon" :icon="['fas','sort']" size="lg" title="TaskStatus" style="font-size:18px;"/></th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' @click="sort('ProductArea')">Product Area<font-awesome-icon id="homeIcon" :icon="['fas','sort']" size="lg" title="TaskStatus" style="font-size:18px;"/></th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' @click="sort('AnalyKind')">Analyses kind<font-awesome-icon id="homeIcon" :icon="['fas','sort']" size="lg" title="TaskStatus" style="font-size:18px;"/></th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' @click="sort('Created')">Created<font-awesome-icon id="homeIcon" :icon="['fas','sort']" size="lg" title="TaskStatus" style="font-size:18px;"/></th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' @click="sort('Visible')">Visible<font-awesome-icon id="homeIcon" :icon="['fas','sort']" size="lg" title="TaskStatus" style="font-size:18px;"/></th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' @click="sort('ComingSoon')">Coming Soon<font-awesome-icon id="homeIcon" :icon="['fas','sort']" size="lg" title="TaskStatus" style="font-size:18px;"/></th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' >Action</th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor='lightgray' >Action</th>
                        </tr>                       
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for ="item in Effdata" v-bind:key="item.Id">
                    <td>{{item['ProductID'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{item['ProductTitle'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{item['Description']}}</td>
                    <td>{{item['ProductArea']}}</td>
                    <td>{{item['AnalyKind']}}</td>
                    <td>{{item['Created']}}</td>
                    <td>{{item['Visible']}}</td>
                    <td>{{item['ComingSoon']}}</td>
                    <td>
                            <button class="btn1" @click="ViewDetailsEdit(item['ProductID'])"><input type="button" class="edit-btn" value="Edit"/></button>
                          </td>
                          <td><input type="button" class="edit-btn btndeleterow" value="Delete" @click="DeleteRecord(item['ProductID'],item['ProductTitle'])"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My vue script is :

```
    <script>

    var API_URL = process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER;
    
    import Lib from '@/assets/lib/commonFunctions.js'
    
    export default{
        name:'ReschkTable',
        data(){
            return{
                Effdata:[],
                filter:'',
                currentSort:'ProductID',
                currentSortDir:'asc',
                pageSize:5,
                currentPage:1,
            }
        },
    methods:{
        sort:function(s) {
          //if s == current sort, reverse
          if(s === this.currentSort) {
            this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir==='asc'?'desc':'asc';
          }
          this.currentSort = s;
        },
        nextPage:function() {
          if((this.currentPage*this.pageSize) < this.filteredCats.length) this.currentPage++;
        },
        prevPage:function() {
          if(this.currentPage > 1) this.currentPage--;
        }
    
      },
        watch: {
        filter() {
          console.log('reset to p1 due to filter');
          this.currentPage = 1;
        }
      },
    
        async mounted(){
            this.Effdata = await Lib.axiosCallApi(API_URL + "getEtbData");
            console.log(this.Effdata);
        
        },
        computed: {
        filteredCats() {
          return this.Effdata.filter(c => {
            if(this.ProductID == '') return true;
            return c.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
          }) 
        },
    
        sortedArray() {
           //This is for Header Sorter for table
           let sortedvalues = this.filteredCats
              return sortedvalues.sort((a,b) => {
                    let modifier = 1;
                    if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc')
                       modifier = -1;
                    if(a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort])
                      return -1 * modifier;
                    if(a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort])
                       return 1 * modifier;
                    return 0;
                  }).filter((row, index) => {
                    let start = (this.currentPage-1)*this.pageSize;
                    let end = this.currentPage*this.pageSize;
                    if(index >= start && index < end) return true;
                  });
            },
            positionText: function () {
              //Showing start and end index data and length of array
              var endIndex = this.currentPage * this.pageSize,
              startIndex = ((this.currentPage - 1) * this.pageSize) + 1;
              return "Showing "+startIndex+ " to "+ (endIndex>this.EmpData.length? this.EmpData.length :endIndex)  + " of " + this.EmpData.length;
        }
      },
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use computed.
and use it to your table

```js
<template>
   ...
   <tr v-for ="item in datatable" v-bind:key="item.Id">
   ...
</template>
export default {
   ...
   computed: {
      // This method will be triggered when there are changes on data value
      // Make sure to put inside the data that needs to be watch
      // Example this.filteredCats
      datatable() {
         let table = this.Effdata
         // Do sort
         // Do filter
         // Use this.filteredCats in order to trigger this computed
         this.filteredCats
         table = table.sort(...)
         table = table.filter(...)
         return table
      }
   }
}
```